# Functional Equation on smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

**Problem:** Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We denote by $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the set of infinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Find all functions $F:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{R}$, verifying the following three properties:

1. $F(f+g)=F(f)+F(g)$ for any $f,g$ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
2. $F(\alpha f)=\alpha F(f)$ for any $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
3. $F(fg)=F(f)g(a)+F(g)f(a)$.

*My attempt:* When $n=1$, one such function is $F(f)=f'(a)$. I could also prove that $F(\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. This is all I could find. Any hint in the right direction, instead of a complete solution, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a hw problem? Or did you up with it on your own?

Comment: @DavidRaveh this is a problem from a past paper of an exam that I am preparing for.

Comment: Hint: The set of all such functions $F$ is a vector space, consider directional derivatives at $a$.

Comment: @jd27 Nice! The partial derivatives at a are the required functions for n>1.  I also did observe that the solutions form a vector space over R, but couldn't use this further. How do you intend to use this? I couldn't even  show that for n=1, the vector space is one-dimensional.

Comment: @TakamotoYuji Any directional derivative at $a$ can be written as the linear combination of certain elementary directional derivatives at $a$ with unique coefficients. To show that any $F$ can be written as such a linear combination consider the action of $F$ onto a Taylor expanded function (with first and second derivative). Its probably easier to consider first the case $n=1$. You may need to derive certain additional properties that any $F$ satisfies when acting on functions with certain properties.

Comment: @jd27 I tried to deal with the case $n=1$, I tried to use Taylor series but the remainder term is problematic. How should I go forward? I also observed that $F((x-a)^k)=0$ for $k\ge 2$, so most of the terms vanish in the taylor series.

Comment: @TakamotoYuji You can show that the $F$ applied to the remainder vanishes using the integral or the peano form of the remainder by rewriting it as the product of two functions that vanish at $a$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147125/discussion-between-takamoto-yuji-and-jd27).